# Firebase security rules: Verify Timestamp type data is the same or later than the requested date

Tags: firebase, firebase-security

I want to verify if the Timestamp type data is the same or later than the requested date.

I wrote rules in this way.

```
task.due_date.date() >= request.time.date()
```

If the date is in the future than the requested date, it works fine.

However, if the date is the same as the date of the request, it cannot be written.

How should the rules be written?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `task` a local variable and is valid and has a valid `due_date` field...

```
task.due_date.toMillis() >= request.time.toMillis()
```

Comment: Thank you for your comments.
That answer is not the solution to the problem.
“due_date” don’t have time, only date (like 2022-05-30 00:00:00). 
However, “request_time” has both date and time.
So, even if they are on the same date, that condition is not true.
I didn’t write this information, sorry.

Comment: That's useful to know, @hbk.  It also gives the answer: store due_date as a real date,  (or add another field due_dateTime which is the due_date represented as a date. This can be done at creation time or in a trigger function, onWrite.